# PHP. Почему не верный ответ?

Tags: php

Проходил задание, в коносли все показывает хорошо, а на сайте, где был тест результат 0 из 4

```
function validate(string $username) : bool {
return !strrpos($username, ' ') &&
       strlen($username) > 3 &&
       substr($username, 0, 1) != '_' &&
       substr($username, -1, 1) != '_' &&
        (preg_match('#[^0-9]#',$username) || preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z]/', $username));
}

echo validate('Mike_Standish') ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'; #Valid username
echo "\n";
echo validate('Mike Standish') ? 'Valid' : 'Invalid'; #Invalid username
```

Я определил, что проверка на числа и буквы неверная. Можно вставить любой специальный символ и будет true. Это ок, не успел сделать. Тест итак бы не прошел. Но он не пройден по всем пунктам, включая длину и начало/конец строки.

Требования:

Реализуйте функцию проверки, которая принимает имя пользователя и
возвращает true, если это приемлемо, и false, если нет.

Имя пользователя допустимо, если оно удовлетворяет следующим правилам:

- Имя пользователя должно содержать не менее 4 символов.
- Имя пользователя должно содержать только буквы, цифры и необязательно
  одно подчеркивание (_).
- Имя пользователя должно начинаться с буквы и не должно заканчиваться
  на подчеркивать.

Например, validate("Майк Стэндиш"); вернет false, потому что это
содержит пробел.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/9QCuWf/1 что-то такое?

Comment: @splash58 третий match не верный, там окончание на _ . Но тут вопрос не в этом. Мой пример тоже не правильный, я тут понял, что охватываю любое кол-во _, а должно быть максимум одно. Но судя по тому, что это все можно было написать регуляркой, то надо было так пробовать. Скорее всего, суть задачи заключалась в этом